# Indefinite article + noun + that + be + adj

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, phrases, sentence-patterns, descriptive-grammar

" On top of their fees, the famous have the potential to earn huge amounts of money from promoting luxury brands. A type of wealth that is possible because celebrities are often seen as role models, and so people want to copy them and buy what they have."

Does " a type of wealth that is possible" mean " that type of wealth is possible"? Why did the writer use that "grammar structure"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*A type of wealth that is possible because celebrities are often seen as role models, and so people want to copy them and buy what they have.* is an elliptical sentence:

> Elliptical sentence construction involves the *omission of words from a sentence.* These omitted words are implied by other elements within the sentence. Elliptical structures include a noun ellipsis, a verb ellipsis, or a verb-phrase ellipsis. ([Masterclass.com](https://www.masterclass.com/articles/how-to-write-an-elliptical-sentence#what-is-elliptical-language))

In your example, the implied elements are in the previous sentence. With the omitted words, it could be written as:

> *[**This** (earning huge amounts of money from promoting luxury brands) **is**]* a type of wealth that is possible...